# Startup redis-server then use bash

Tags: docker

```
# Redis
    # Download and extract Redis source files
RUN curl -o redis.tar.gz "http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.2.tar.gz" && \
    mkdir redis_tmp/ && \
    tar xzf redis.tar.gz -C redis_tmp && \
    # Rename temporary directory
    mv redis_tmp/* redis && \
    # Install Redis
    cd redis && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    # Remove source files
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf redis && \
    # Confirm installation
    redis-server -v

# Cleanup
    # Remove local repository package files
RUN apt-get -y clean

ENTRYPOINT redis-server

CMD bash
```

Here the last part of my Dockerfile. I'd like to run the following command:

```
docker run -it test_image
```

I'd like this image to startup redis-server and leave me using bash.

It leaves me with redis-server though:

````
kmorrison@Karl ~/dev/test_image (master) $ docker run -it test_image
9:C 06 Oct 10:09:23.266 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
9:C 06 Oct 10:09:23.266 # Redis version=4.0.2, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=9, just started
9:C 06 Oct 10:09:23.266 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 4.0.2 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 9
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

9:M 06 Oct 10:09:23.268 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
9:M 06 Oct 10:09:23.268 # Server initialized
9:M 06 Oct 10:09:23.268 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
9:M 06 Oct 10:09:23.268 * Ready to accept connections
````

It has something to do with ENTRYPOINT and CMD.

Comment: Can you do `RUN redis-server &` to run the server in background? entrypoint doesn't fit that kind of use

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I tried that. But then my CI that uses the image hangs because it nevers gets past the command (since it's active in the foreground). I need to daemonize it somehow.

Comment: Weird, `&` should send the process in background, but never tried on docker. I guess you can also try to launch `redis-server` as docker `CMD` and then connect to the container launching the bash `docker exec -it {container-id} /bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your redis configuration:
`daemonize yes` or start it with `redis-server --daemonize yes` to daemonize the Redis service.

Alternatively you can start Redis from systemd or upstart.

**Update:** `ENTRYPOINT redis-server --daemonize yes && bash` proved to be the working solution for the original poster.

Comment: This starts the Redis daemon now (thanks), but now exits (does not let me use bash in the running container).

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT redis-server --daemonize yes && bash`, worked. Update your answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

This question is painfully old, but my search found it, so I'll offer an answer.

You misunderstand the relationship between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in an image.

`ENTRYPOINT` is the command interpreter, if you will. It is the program that executes the specified command. When a container based on this image is started, it will run <`ENTRYPOINT`> <`CMD`>. So you are saying you want to run `redis-server bash` which is highly unlikely to do what you intended.

While you are free to make your `ENTRYPOINT` be **redis-server**, it would be more normal to leave it unset. More naturally, you would set `CMD redis-server` and run your image as a daemon, then exec into it as needed:

```bash
docker run --rm -d -p 6379:6379 --name redis my-image
docker exec -it redis bash
```